# Handle filter exception in control advice in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, exception, controller-advice, spring-filter

Hi I have a global exception handler and I do something if exceptions occurs.But I have spring filters and spring filters cannot catch in my globalexceptionhandler.I read similar post in stackoverflow but still confused.Is there a way to catch filter exception in control advice

```
  @RestControllerAdvice 
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
    
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)  
public ResponseEntity handleAllException(Exception ex, WebRequest request){
 //To something in exception case
//Except filter exception All exceptions catched here
}
```